# Use vue3-cookies in custom plugin

Tags: plugins, vuejs3

I want to use vue3-cookies in my custom plugin, but whatever I do I keep getting undefined.

MyPlugin.js

```
export default {
    install: (app, options) => {
        app.config.globalProperties.$MyPlugin= {
            someFunction() {
                console.log(app.cookie);
                console.log(app.cookies);
                console.log(app.$cookies);
            }
        }
    },
};
```

app.js

```
import {createApp} from 'vue';
import VueCookies from 'vue3-cookies'
import MyPlugin from "./plugins/MyPlugin";

const app = createApp({});
app.use(VueCookies)
app.use(MyPlugin)
const mountedApp = app.mount('#app');
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I clearly missed a piece while reading the documentation.

This did the trick.

https://github.com/KanHarI/vue3-cookies#usage---via-composition-api-recommended

```
import {useCookies} from "vue3-cookies";

export default {
    install: (app, options) => {
        app.config.globalProperties.$MyPlugin = {
            someFunction() {
                const {cookies} = useCookies();
                
                console.log(cookies.get('cookie_name'));
            }
        }
    },
};
```